# Rails bulk insert with relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with `bulk inserts` with RoR, using [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) gem.

I have following code

```
 User.bulk_insert(:username, :email, :password) do |worker|
    100000.times do
      worker.add username: 'aadsad', email: 'some@email', password: 'some password'
    end
  end
```

and everyting works properly.

The problem occurrs when i want to insert data with has_one relationship.
How can i insert relationship data to created entry ?

I try:

```
  User.bulk_insert(:username, :email, :password, user_detail_attributes: [:firstname, :last_name, :phone, :city]) do |worker|
    100000.times do
      worker.add username: 'aadsad', email: 'some@email', password: 'some password', firstname: 'firstname', lastname: 'lastname', phone: '41', city: 'city'
    end
  end
```

but no effect, I receive error:

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: user_detail_attributes
```

Comment: Does the `User` model have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details`?

Comment: Kris of course it have